# force figure placement in twocolumn elsarticle

Tags: floats, two-column, elsarticle

i'm trying to include a lot of figures in twocolumn elsarticle document class, however the  figures are not placed where i wanted , here an example of figure's code :

```
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\captionsetup[Fig.]{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
...
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.70\textwidth{C:/Users/awijen/Desktop/str/Figures/agrst.eps}
    \caption{agriculture}
    \label{fig:agrst}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: You write, "the figures are not placed where i wanted". Where do you want them?

Comment: just after the text

Comment: You're out of luck,then: in a two-column LaTeX document, full-width floats will only be placed either at the top of a page or at the very end of the document.

Comment: but  placement may still depend on the size of the included image.!!

Comment: Ah, I had overlooked the fact that you're loading the `dblfloatfix` package. Doing so gives you `t` (top), `b` (bottom), and `p` (full-page) as the three positioning choices. Note that `h` ("here") is not among the choices.